# How can I add inline css in laravel blade syntax button?

Tags: css, laravel-blade, inline-styles

I want to add style attribute like the normal HTML button element

```
<button type="button" style="background-color: #b4b7b7">Load</button>
```

in this button

```
{{ Form::submit('Load', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code in Laravels blade with [LaravelCollective's HTML](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#buttons)

```php
{{ Form::button('Load', ['type' => 'button', 'style' => 'background-color: #b4b7b7']) }}
```

should produce the following html

```html
<button type="button" style="background-color: #b4b7b7">Load</button>
```